# How to move search bar center to top of the page?

Tags: html, css

I want to move a search bar from center of the page to top of same page otherwise next page just like Google search do.
I need good suggestion please help me out.

This is my search bar code:

```
    <div class="big-search-box"> 
    <form role="form" class=""> 
        <div class="input-group"> 
            <input type="text" placeholder="Input your search query..." class="form-control nrb input-lg"> 
            <div class="input-group-btn"> 
                <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle btn-iconed btn-lg" type="button">
                    <i class="fa fa-file-text-alt"></i> <span>Search</span>
                </button> 
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </form> 
</div>
```

Comment: can you show us your code?

Comment: It's just a search bar code in Html page that i want to move from center to top

Comment: Update your question, not post your code as a comment... This question is very wide... Please be as specific as possible, and also remember to use the right tags. I'm pretty sure you dont want to do this kind of GUI things with PHP..?

Answer (score 1):

You should provide some code in order to help us, help you.
 Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Css positioning should do the trick, and since we have no code, ill refer you to this [article](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) I found online.

Example:

```
div.relative {
position: relative;
left: 30px;
border: 3px solid #73AD21;}
```

Edit: Thanks for adding the code, this should do the trick

```
.big-search-box {
position: relative;
width: 50%;
left: 25%;
top: 350px;
}
```

You can change the above piece of css to whatever suits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

When on the main page it would look like this:

```
width: 50%; //centered in the middle of the page
left: 25%;
top: 500px;
position: absolute;
```

And then when you enter the search result page (like google) it would look like this:

```
width: 50%; //moved to upper left corner (like google)
left: 1%;
top: 5px;
position: absolute;
```

Comment: please can you tell how can i use these css snippet with same submit button. Thanks in advanced

Comment: oh you got me there, try and give it 2 classes with different names, and link the snippets to those. Give it a shot.